# Unable to access global variables inside foreach on Mocha framework v8.4.0

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, jasmine, mocha.js, webdriver-io

I recently updated to Mocha v8.4.0 which is the latest. I am using Mocha with webdriverIO v7. I have initialized my global variable ex: `global.testuser1 = testuser1` and the same for other users in before hook in wdio.config.js. `testuser1` is a variable.

I have a spec file on which I would like to access the above global variable and the spec file looks as follows

```
let login = [{username: testuser1, password: testpass1}, {username: testuser2, password: testpass2}]

login.forEach(function(user) {
  describe('testing login for multiple users', function() {
    before(function() {
      login.loginUser(user.username, user.password); <-- just an example method call here to pass the global variables
    }

    it('do something', function() {
      console.log('successful')
    }
  }
}
```

I keep on getting:

> Error: ReferenceError: testuser1 is not defined

The same test used to work fine on v5 of webdriverio and Mocha 5.*.*

Comment: It's not at all clear from the code you posted why you think `testuser1` should be defined.

Comment: @Pointy variables defined in before hook inside wdio.config file will be available through out the execution and I have made them global. Please let me know if this is not clear. Other tests work fine when I don't have forEach loop